# How do I create a Resize animation for JavaFX stage?

Tags: java, javafx

I've been trying to make a scaling transition for a JavaFX stage to replaces the current Scene (in this case a login frame) for an application's main window.
When this happens, since the new scene is bigger, the windows gets re-sized abruptly in a non-elegant manner.

Is there any way to set up a scaling or re-size transition to do this to the stage resizing?

Relevant code:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fxml/principal.fxml");
    Region pagina = (Region) cargadorFXML.load(is);
    cargadorFXML.<ContenedorPrincipal>getController().setEscenario(escenario);

    final Scene escena = new Scene(pagina, 900, 650);

    escena.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    escenario.setScene(escena);
    escenario.sizeToScene();
    escenario.centerOnScreen();
    escenario.show();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // log "Unable to load the main application driver"
    log.error("No fue posible cargar el controlador principal de la aplicación."); 
    log.catching(ex);
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really liked your idea so I managed to do a little something.
I hope this will help you.

I used a `Timer` to change the stage width and height every 25ms in order to give the impression of an animation.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SmoothResize extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Area Chart Sample");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene  = new Scene(root, 250, 250);
        stage.setResizable(false);

        Timer animTimer = new Timer();
        animTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int i=0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i<100) {
                    stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()+3);
                    stage.setHeight(stage.getHeight()+3);
                } else {
                    this.cancel();
                }
                i++;
            }

        }, 2000, 25);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it. I opted for creating a new Stage and using fading transitions beetween them to do it in a ellegant manner but your suggestion seems good so i'll try it as soon as i can.

Comment: Better to use JavaFX's built-in animation facilities such as Timeline rather than a Timer.  With a timer you have a different thread and the code is not thread safe unless you wrap the calls that manipulate the stage or scene graph in Platform.runLater() invocations.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use animation mechanism with [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).
Some example is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/animation.htm).

The only problem is that `Stage` do not have writable height or width property and You have to create it by Your own. Example below.

```
WritableValue<Double> writableHeight = new WritableValue<Double>() {
    @Override
    public Double getValue() {
        return stage.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Double value) {
        stage.setHeight(value);
    }
};
```

Comment: Rather than providing example links, could you answer the question with a full example?